# How to offer multi language and country options on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and I need it configured to the following specifications.

I want to have a different URL for each country, e.g. www.mywebsite.com/de/ for Germany. Note: I want to target about 40 countries, each with their own extension, e.g. /es/. This is

Each country will be set up in Google webmaster tools as a top level domain as per the extension, e.g. /es/. This is for SEO purposes.

The issue is when setting a country code it can relate to more then one country, e.g. /es/ (Spanish) can relate to Spain, Colombia and other Spanish speaking countries.

This means if I use the URL /es/ for Spain, I can't use /es/ for Colombia also.

Below are two potential plugins I have looked into but don't seem to have the complete solution.
http://wpml.org/
http://polylang.wordpress.com/

I tried using the second plugin listed above but you cant have multiple "country/Locale" names with the same language code. e.g. /es/ can't be used twice and has to be unique.

I tried changing the language code data and using the country code. This doesn't work because the code relates to a language as defined in the settings. This means the html the plugin uses results in the wrong language e.g. (hreflang="es") see below detailing entering country code and incorrect language inserted.

This works as "es" is a language code"

This doesn't work. "br" for Brazil should be "pr" for the country Portuguese

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'Bogo' plugin? This is a multilingual plugin just like WPML or qTranslate. I just started using this plugin, so I'm still studying into it. However, I have the feeling that this plugin is what you wanted.

This plugin uses /country-LOCALE/ for different countries and languages as defined in here: http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/